# How to find representation of symmetry operation in magnon system?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, representation-theory, magnetic-moment

Suppose an anti-ferromagnetic system with $n$ inequivalent atoms which is described by a Heisenberg Hamiltonian. The symmetry group of a given wave vector $G_k$ and how those inequivalent atoms transform under each symmetry operation of the group is already known. **The goal is to find ( generally reducible ) representations of $G_k$ in $n$ bare boson basis at $k$ ( i.e., basis before Bogoliubov transformation ).**

To be more specific, after Fourier transformation but before diagonalization we have the form:
$$H=\sum_{\mathbf{k}} \Psi_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger} H_{\mathbf{k}} \Psi_{\mathbf{k}}$$
where $\Psi_{\mathbf{k}}=\left[a_{1 \mathbf{k}} \cdots a_{n \mathbf{k}} | a_{1-\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger} \cdots a_{n-\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\right]^{T}$ gives the bare boson basis at $k$ and $H_{\mathbf{k}}$ is not diagonalized. As long as we can find how $a_{1 \mathbf{k}} \cdots a_{n \mathbf{k}}$ transforms under symmetry operation, we can get the desired representation.

My naive thought is filling the matrix element $\Gamma_{ij}$ by 1 if $j$th atom tranforms to $i$th atom after the symmetry operation and by 0 otherwise. Thus we will get the following form
$$\Psi_{\mathbf{k}} \rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cc}\Gamma & 0 \\ 0 & \Gamma^{*}\end{array}\right) \Psi_{\mathbf{k}}$$
where $\Gamma$ is just a permutation matrix.

However I've found in some paper ( in the Supplemental Material of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.08170.pdf ) that each non-zero matrix element may have a phase factor such as:
$$\Gamma \left( C_3 \right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}e^{i 2 \pi / 3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e^{i \pi / 3} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & e^{i 2 \pi / 3} & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

The information about the spin configuration of ground state, the positions of inequivalent atoms and symmetry operation is given below:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}\hline \hline \text { atom }(m) & \vec{\mathrm{r}}_{m} & \vec{\mathrm{S}}_{m} \\ \hline 1 & (0,0,0) & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\overline{1}, \overline{1}, \overline{1}) \\ 2 & (0,1,1) & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\overline{1}, 1,1) \\ 3 & (1,0,1) & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1, \overline{1}, 1) \\ 4 & (1,1,0) & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1, \overline{1}) \\ \hline \hline\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{lc}\hline \hline \mathcal{O} \text { (symmetry operation) } & \mathcal{O}: \vec{r}=(x, y, z) \rightarrow \vec{r}^{\prime}=\left(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime}, z^{\prime}\right) \\ \hline & & \\ \left.C_{3} \text { [rotation axis: }(x, x, x)\right] & (y, z, x) \\ & \\ \hline\end{array}$$

**So here's my question: What's the form of wavefunction corresponding to those bare boson creation/annihilation operators $a_{1 \mathbf{k}} \cdots a_{n \mathbf{k}}$? How can we decide the phase factor of each matrix element?**